# Updating values from server and sending notification in a time interval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

let's say I want to generate a notification every 10 seconds using setInterval, and make that function call the server to see if data has changed.
I'm not being able to do this using the code below. 
Can someone help me achieve this?

Here is the function. I'm using subscribe to call a function to get data from server.

```
checkValidStatus(){
    this.getEvent.getCommandStatus(this.idComandoLog).subscribe(res=>{ 

      this.mComandoStatus = res;

      switch (this.mComandoStatus) {
        case "0":
          this.genNotif.genNotificationNow(this.COMANDO_ID_0, this.COMANDO_TITLE_BLOCK, this.COMANDO_RESPONSE_0);          
         break;
        case "1":
          this.genNotif.genNotificationNow(this.COMANDO_ID_1, this.COMANDO_TITLE_BLOCK, this.COMANDO_RESPONSE_1);          
         break;
        default:
         break;
       }


    })

  }
```

This is getCommandStatus, where I call my server and there I'm retrieving values from a webservice that changes from time to time.

```
getCommandStatus(idComandoLog){


    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/commandstatus', {
      a: idComandoLog

    }, {
      responseType:'text'
    })

  }
```

And this is where I'm trying to do the call every 10 seconds.

```
setInterval(this.cmd.checkValidStatus(), 10000);
```

Is there a better approach to do this? To update a value that has changed in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but, what if you call checkValidStatus in arrow function:

```
setInterval(() => this.cmd.checkValidStatus(), 10000);
```

Comment: Awesome, can't believe it was so simple. Thank you, sir!